# Alarm Manager not working when app closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I've been stuck on this for days now.
I want my alarm manager to fire off every 15 minutes even when the app is closed but it does not work when app is closed. It works while app is open though.

In my manifest file I have:

```
  <!-- Used to consume the alarm manager alerts when app clsoed -->
    <receiver
       android:name="biz.customName.pkg.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="biz.customName.pkg.msg"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My BroadcastReceiver class (AlarmReceiver)

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

// Alarm manager used to run install when app is closed
AlarmManager alarmManager;


// Called when alarm received
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    // Enable alarm
    setupAlarm(context);

    // Perform background task 
}


// Setup alarm
public void setupAlarm(Context context)
{
    // Setup reciever for alarm
  //  context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter("biz.customName.pkg.msg"));

    // Setup pending intent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(Loader.filterName), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Setup alarm
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    final long triggerTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 900 * 1000;

    // Newest OS
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23)
    {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
    }
 }
}
```

In main I call setup alarm to get the alarm going initially then each time the onReceive inside my Broadcast receiver is called I reset the alarm.

What am I doing wrong that it doesn't work when the app is closed?

Comment: What device are you testing this on?

Comment: Please show what else you are doing in the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Tested on Nexus5 and Galaxy Nexus
This is my whole broadcast receiver class.

Comment: What do you mean by "app is closed"? How do you "close" the app?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the `BroadcastReceiver` is being called? How can you tell if it is being called?

Comment: If app is forced closed by user. 
And yes I have break points in broadcast receiver to confirm it was being hit before closing the app.

Comment: Ahh...that explains it. If the user force closes your app there is nothing you can do. Force close puts your app into the "stopped state". In this state, your `BroadcastReceiver`s will not be called. Ever. Until the user manually starts your app again (by tapping the app icon) which will bring the app out of the stopped state. "Force close" is not something that users should normally do. This is bad news. If your app behaves itself the user should not need to "force close" it.

Comment: There's no way to be able to run an updater in the background every few hours? I can't speak for all users but myself, I force close all my apps every so often to keep my battery life at the best it can be and allow the garbage collector to run.

Comment: No. When the user force closes an app, he is telling Android that he doesn't want the app to run anymore. You will see a warning when you force close an app that says specifically that the app may not work correctly. This is why that dialog is shown. Force closing apps is a bad idea.

Comment: @mocode10 were you able to resolve?

Comment: Did you find the solution ??

Answer (score 2):

**Add this in your AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
android:name=".MyService"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true" />

<receiver
android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true" />
```

**MyAlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;

public MyAlarmReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}

}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   YourTask();

  return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void YourTask(){
    // call api in background 

   // send push notification 

   //etc...
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
Intent alarmIntent;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AutoUpdateDataInBackground();
    }

 private void AutoUpdateDataInBackground() {
    // Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast

    alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    long interval = 15 * 60 * 1000;

    // Repeating on every 15 minutes interval

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),interval, pendingIntent);
}

}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot in the morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

BTW : AlarmManager will not be called with locked screen and enabled energy saving mode