# Not able to show notifications when app is closed in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-service

I am trying to implement a background service which notifies me every continuously. So for that I'm using **Alarm manager and broadcast receiver**. This is my broadcast receiver code

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] {PeriodicService.AlarmService, "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
    public class BackgroundReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "BackgroundReceiver");
            wakeLock.Acquire();
            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10), () =>
            {
                // do something every 60 seconds
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {

                    Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "Hi when app opened", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    NotificationCenter.NotifyNotificationTapped(intent);
                   
                    var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                      .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
                                      .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Alarm)
                                      .Build();

                   // var alarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("Resources/Audio/AlarmSound.wav");
                    NotificationCenter.Current.Show((notification) => notification
                           .WithScheduleOptions((schedule) => schedule
                           .Build())
                           
                           .WithAndroidOptions((android) => android
                                .WithAutoCancel(true)
                                .WithChannelId("General")
                                
                                .WithPriority(Plugin.LocalNotification.NotificationPriority.High)
                                .Build())
                           .WithiOSOptions((ios) => ios
                               .ShouldPlayForegroundSound(true)
                               .Build())
                           .WithReturningData("Dummy Data")
                           .WithTitle("Test Title")
                           .WithDescription("Test Description")
                           .WithNotificationId(100)
                           .Create());
                    Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "HI", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "UpdateLabel", "Hello from Android");
                });
                return true; // runs again, or false to stop
            });

            wakeLock.Release();
        }
    }
```

This is my **background service code**

```
[Service]
    public class PeriodicService : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            // From shared code or in your PCL
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "UpdateLabel", "Hello from Android");
       
            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10), () =>
            {
                // do something every 60 seconds
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "Hi when app closed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                  
                });
                return true; // runs again, or false to stop
            });
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

    }
```

This is my **Main activity code**

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        global::Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
        

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(BackgroundReceiver));
        BackgroundReceiver myreceiver = new BackgroundReceiver();
        RegisterReceiver(myreceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"));
        //StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(PeriodicService)));
        // CreateNotificationChannel();
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            //DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning();
            //StartForegroundService(Intent);
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(PeriodicService)));
        }
        else
        {
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(PeriodicService)));
        }

       
        //alarmIntent.PutExtra("message", "This is my test message!");
        //alarmIntent.PutExtra("title", "This is my test title!");
        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        //AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        //alarmManager.SetAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, DateTime.Now.Millisecond + 5000, pendingIntent);

    }
```

This is my code in **manifest**

```
<application android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:allowBackup="false" android:label="myproject">
        <receiver android:name=".BackgroundReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote" android:label="myproject" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

This is my **code where I request for permission**.

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

I have gone through many solutions but nothing helped me. These are the links I have gone through

[Android - AlarmManager is not working after app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186458/android-alarmmanager-is-not-working-after-app-is-closed)

[Alarm Manager not working when app closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425668/alarm-manager-not-working-when-app-closed)

I tried to use **foreground services** as well this is my service code

```
  public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            // From shared code or in your PCL
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "UpdateLabel", "Hello from Android");
            
            
                    CreateNotificationChannel();
                    DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
        public void DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning()
        {
            
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)

            .SetVibrate(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 })
            .SetSound(null)

            .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
            .SetAutoCancel(false)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_icon_background)
            .SetContentTitle("test")
            .SetContentText("service started")
            .SetOngoing(true);
            
            Notification bui = mBuilder.Build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, bui);
            StartForeground(121, bui);
            
        }

        public void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {

                return;
            }

            var channelName = "Notification_Channel";
            var channelDescription = "Foreground Notification";
            var channel = new NotificationChannel("10121", channelName, NotificationImportance.High)
            {
                Description = channelDescription
            };

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

Till now I'm getting the notification channel in the app settings  but notification is not showing for me. I am using a **Redmi note 8 device** and my **target android version is Android 11.0(API level 30)**. I have gone through app which meets my requirement that is **StepSetGo** you can find that in playstore you can see that **application continuously shows notification** even if the **app is killed** and it records the number of steps without internet . I have given the same permission for this application also like **autostart and no battery restrictions** but still it doesn't work. I have no clue how to fix this any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I missed it ... Where is your code that checks **at run-time** whether your app has actually been given the permission **by the user**, and if not, does the appropriate call to Android, which will bring up a standard Android dialog that the **user can accept or deny**? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows#runtime-permission-checks-in-android-60

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have added the code where I'm asking for permission.

Comment: So far so good. Now see [Checking Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=ios#checking-permissions), and check the `status` that is returned.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yeah the permissions are fine but still the app is not running when it is closed.

Comment: Do you mind working with FCM notifications?

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete yes you can mention the FCM implementation of both Android and iOS.

Comment: Yes, you can use `FCM` to achieve this function.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT my main requirement is to implement local notification for Android and since local notification will not work for iOS because of Apple rules. So for iOS I will need FCM.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT my priority is local notification for android because I need to notify the user even in local mode without internet when ever my sensor sends a signal using TCP.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT if notification is not possible then I need to show an alert with a sound when app is closed and running in background.

Comment: Can you make sure that your service will always run? Services running in the background can consume device resources, potentially resulting in a worse user experience. To mitigate this problem, the system applies a number of limitations on services.For more ,please check: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broadcast receiver will die with the app. I would use the service to start the broadcast receiver and have it talk directly to the service.

In your service:
MyReceiver myreceiver = new MyReceiver(this);
RegisterReceiver(myreceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.MyReceiver");

In your receiver:

service.Notify("IT'S WAKE UP TIME!");

Also, I noticed your service doesn't have a notification running permanently. It will be killed by the OS.

In your Service:
StartForeground(intID, notification);

Comment: In my code I'm using a service called PeriodicService will that be fine or should I create a separate service. Your answer seems to be relevant could you please elaborate.

Comment: Each service you create has to have a permanent notification. You can create more, if you'd like. But I don't understand the purpose of your PeriodicService. I would use it to keep the receiver running and show notifications when the app is sent to the background, or closed.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it doesn't work for me. Also I have edited my question please have a look into it.

Comment: Everything you want to do when the app is dead has to be in the Service, your PeriodicService. If the app is dead, the thread running your code will stop. The service will have to do everything. In my case, I needed a service to capture activity changes. I'm starting the service, starting the receiver from within the service. On receive, I tell the service what to do at that time. You service has a notification, but it has no logic to react, or do anything. It just exists. Think of the service as an independent entity which can do things, regardless of the App's state.

Comment: If you have a link or an example. That will be beneficial.